# Crashing RAM using memmap in Oja rule

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, numpy-memmap, neupy

I am using oja's rule on dataset of size 400x156300. It seems to crash my RAM. I am not sure what is causing this. Please help.
I have 12 GB of RAM.
Tried using memmap but still crashing!!

```
#convert memmap and reduce precision
[num_sample,num_feat]=train_data.shape
filename = path.join(mkdtemp(), 'train_data.dat')
memmap_train = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(num_sample,num_feat))
memmap_train[:] = train_data[:]
del train_data,test_data

#apply oja's rule
ojanet = algorithms.Oja(minimized_data_size=1250,step=1e-10,verbose=True,show_epoch=1)
ojanet.train(memmap_train, epsilon=1e-3,epochs=10000)
red_train_data = ojanet.predict(memmap_train)
ojanet.plot_errors(logx=False)
pdb.set_trace()
```

Also, raised issue:https://github.com/itdxer/neupy/issues/27. Don't know if the package development is active.

By crashing RAM I mean the RAM % utilization goes beyond 100% and my computer stops responding.

Comment: What does it mean to "crash your RAM"? Do you mean Python core dumps? Or something else? Because "crashing RAM" is nonsense.

Comment: Also, memmap may fill all available RAM memory at first, so it's normal thing, it just reads from HDD as much as it can. In your case i'd better look at progress of algorithm, if it works.

You can try to use sparse matrices if it's possible.

Comment: On which line does the problem occur?

Comment: @ali_m `ojanet.train(memmap_train, epsilon=1e-3,epochs=10000)`.

Answer (score 0):

This issues was related to the inefficient memory usage for the Oja algorithm. It was fixed in the NeuPy version 0.1.4. Closed ticket you can find here: https://github.com/itdxer/neupy/issues/27